# Set Font colour based on a condition (Google-Sheets AppScript)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This question is related to Google-Sheets App Script

I am trying to compare two values from the source sheet to two values in
target sheet respectively then based on the row number found in the
target sheet I want to change the font colour of this  cell to that of
the font-clour of the cell found in column-E of the target sheet.

My Logic is shown below.
SrcSheet = Batches-sheet
TargetSheet = Activity-sheet

> if srcDate is found in the targetDateRange in TargetSheet AND  if
>   srcBatchName is found in the targetBatchNameRange in TargetSheet THEN
>   set the font-colour of this cell (srcDate in srcSheet)  to the
>   fontcolour of targetLessonCell of in TargetSheet

My Function definition and Function Call looks like this;

Function Call:

```
=updateBatchActivity(W18,Activity!B1:B700,I18,Activity!E1:E700)
```

Function Definition:

```
function updateBatchActivity() {      
var app = SpreadsheetApp;


  var sourceSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Batches"); 
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Activity");  

  for (var srcRow=3; srcRow<=8; srcRow++) {
    srcBatch = sourceSheet.getRange(srcRow,9).getValue()
    Logger.log('Row ' + srcRow + ' BatchName: ' + srcBatch);
     for (var srcCol=21;srcCol<=36; srcCol++) {
       var range = sourceSheet.getRange(srcRow,srcCol);
       srcDate = range.getValue()

       for (var dstRow=2; dstRow<=10; dstRow++) {
         var targetDate = targetSheet.getRange(dstRow,2).getValue();
         if (srcDate == targetDate) {
           var targetBatch = targetSheet.getRange(dstRow,5).getValue();
           if (srcBatch == targetBatch) {
             var fontColour = targetSheet.getRange(dstRow,6).getFontColour();
             range.setFontColor(fontColour);
           }
         }
       }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Google Apps Script is based upon JavaScript 1.6 and it does not contain `is found in`.  Also it appears that this declaration conflicts with one of your parameters `var srcBatchName = sheet.getRange(srcBatchName);`

Comment: @Ranchoddas shyamaldas chanchad I think that providing a sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you want will help users think of your solution.

Comment: The program just says preparing for execution

Comment: I'm no expert on this, but shouldn't the function definition include and identify the four variables that it accepts; and then uses in the code. So if you call `updateBatchActivity(W18,Activity!B1:B700,I18,Activity!E1:E700)`, the actual function definition should look something like `function updateBatchActivity(var1,var2,var3,var4){}`, and each of var1,2,3,&4 are declared  and used in the balance of the function code.